# To maximise SEO traffic to an event listing site, should I store pre-generate search results?

Tags: seo

I have a site listing events. It's tiny and in beta. These events have a category, location and time. I want to try to ensure I capture as much SEO traffic as possible. To that end, I was planning on creating a whole series of pre-generated search results pages on my site for 500k permutations of categories/locations/times. E.g. Sports/Today/Chicago, Music/Tomorrow/Chicago, Art/Today/New York etc. These would target search queries along those lines of 'sports events tonight chicago' etc. By my calcs, there will be 500k such permutations. I was planning on re-running queries each day to populate these pages 500k with fresh events. Is that the best approach? And will that be so many pages that I'll need to start considering infrastructure issues?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly something that generates results - a simple search for a specific downloadable book/video will show a ton of pages like the ones you described.

Have in mind that a large number of pages with very little content and a big number of links could be seen by search engines as suspicious and can negatively impact your ranking, so don't overdo it.

Make sure all the pages use a proper navigation and most importantly that they provide something valuable to the visitor. If visitors are not interested in the content and have a very low amount of time spent on your site this will harm your rankings.